# Does PHP optimize initialization of static data when accepting a new request?

Tags: php

Suppose I have a PHP include file only with a big generated static data structure, so something like this:

```
<? define('STATICDATA', ['something => ['stuff1' => ['stuff2' => ....
```

I'm wondering if PHP optimizes loading this data into memory for every request. I know about opcode cache and that the parsed code is stored in memory, I'd just like to know if the loaded file contains such static data then does PHP optimizes it by preparing a memory image of this file and simply does a memory copy for a new request? Or does it execute the opcodes even if it's the same initialization every time?

It's not about performance in my case I'm just curious if the PHP VM is smart enough to optimize loading this data or it handles it the same way as any other code and executes it every time a new request comes.

Comment: Normally it would execute the opcodes every time. PHP 7.4 does have opcode preloading that will keep things you tell it to in-memory for longer than a single request though but you have to explicitly set it up

Comment: @apokryfos if I use define then the data can't change, right? So why do you have to tell PHP about it? Couldn't it, for example, just copy this data into a memory area used to keep constants and refer to that location every time this data is accessed, skipping the initialization?

Comment: It's a bit more complicated than that. I would think. The data needs to be in a memory location accessible by PHP and in a format PHP understands. There usually no spillover between different requests in PHP so you can't directly share data between the PHP requests even if they are handled by the same PHP worker process since everything gets disposed of at the end of each request. I think the closest to what you're describing is using some sort of memory cache like memcache but that still doesn't store raw PHP understandable memory

Comment: I see no reason why the PHP VM couldn't share a data area between requests which only contains constant data, so there are no concurrency issues.

Comment: I'm not saying it couldn't, I'm saying it doesn't, there's no real PHP VM in the sense that there's no PHP container constantly running in the background, so there's nothing persistent running to keep that data in memory. The closest thing is the PHP-FPM worker but that also doesn't always have a long lifetime and is built on top of traditional PHP which didn't have any sort of persistence in memory traditionally.